# XPath based on node indexes only

Tags: xpath

I have an XML :

```
<Section>
    <Paragraph>
        <Text>t1</Text>
        <Text>t2</Text>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
        <Text>t3</Text>
        <Text>t4</Text>
    </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

and I know only element indexes, e.g., /0/1/0 i.e. first Section, second Paragraph, and its first Text. How can I translate '0/1/0' into a valid XPath that returns  element where t3 is ?

Note that I don't know element names because they can differ but I only know sequence of indexes as in above example.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example given this will work.

```
/element()[1]/element()[2]/element()[1]/text()
```